# property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set title of `UINavigationController` I am using following command  `self.title = @"Categories";` it works perfectly, But I needs to name it via an array's object, so I used to put following line of code in `ViewDidLoad` section

```
self.title =@"%@", currentYouga.yougaName;
```

and it giving error **"property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects"**

Comment: do you meant to use it like this self.title =currentYouga.yougaName;?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
self.title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentYouga yougaName]];
```

***This Error comes when you access  arbitrary methods using dot notation,  if yougaName is a method. You cannot access yougaName through dot notation; only properties can access using a method of the same name with dot notation.

Comment: There is no need to do this. self.title = currentYouga.yougaName; is fine.

Comment: @teja : i provide reason why i suggest above answer. please tell me if it is wrong or some thing missing

Comment: @NSSam There is absolutely no reason at all to have that `stringWithFormat:` call in there.  Beyond being extra code that isn't needed, it'll (likely -- NSString may optimize this special case) create an extra copy of the string.

Comment: As well, the error given by the compiler is because OP put an extra "," in the expression, which means that the result of the dot syntax expression is unused.